# Objects with the same attributes and methods belongs to the same class?

Tags: oop, class, object, hierarchy, ambiguity

Objects with the same attributes and methods belongs to the same class?

1. Can't I declare two identical classes with the same methods and attributes, instanciate them and have "**objects with the same attributes and methods belonging to different classes**"?
2. Can't I declare a class A and a sub-class B (children of the class A) both with the same methods and attributes (and don't declare any new attribute or method on the class B), instanciate them and have "**objects with the same attributes and methods belonging to different classes**"?

This question is not about good practices... It's about the logical value (true or false) of the question on the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify what language(s) you're talking about; perhaps there's some exotic language that has the property you describe, but at least in languages like Java and C++ there's no concept of inferring that two classes are "the same" based on what methods/instance variables they declare.

So, the answer is "no, they are not the same class, even though they look the same".

The sub-class case is a little different: if you declare `B` as a subclass of `A` (without adding any methods or variables), they are still different classes, but an object of class `B` also "`is-a`" `A`, because of normal inheritance rules.

Answer (score 1):

Thats definitely possible.

```
class A
{

    public string Property1{get;set;}
    public string Method1(int value)
    {
      ......
    }

}

class B
{
   public string Property1{get;set;}
   public string Method1(int value)
   {
     ........
   }
}
```

Both classes are identical. Have the same properties and methods. But their instances will be different.